# Is this iterative implementation of merge sort correct?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

It seems deceptively simple to me. Note this doesn't produce single element arrays by splitting in half, but through instead using a single loop.

```
function mergeSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = [arr[i]]
  }
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
      arr.splice(i, 2, mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr[i], arr[i + 1] || []))
    }
  }
  return arr[0]
}
```

My tests are passing, but perhaps the time/space complexity isn't as good?

Answer (score 2):

`arr.splice(i, 2, ...)` will need to shift the content that follows `i`, so this is not a constant time operation, and so you exceed the time complexity of *O(nlogn)* that you would expect to get with Merge Sort.

To resolve this, I would suggest to not splice anything out of the array at all, but just skip the array entries that are no longer relevant.

```js
function mergeSort(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = [arr[i]];
    }
    for (let step = 1; step < arr.length; step *= 2) {
        for (let i = 0; i + step < arr.length; i += step*2) {
            arr[i] = mergeTwoSortedArrays(arr[i], arr[i+step]);
            delete arr[i+step]; // optional; to have it garbage collected
        }
    }
    return arr[0];
}

function mergeTwoSortedArrays(a, b) {
    let merged = [];
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < a.length || j < b.length) {
        merged.push(
            i < a.length && (j >= b.length || a[i] < b[j])
            ? a[i++]
            : b[j++]
        );
    }
    return merged;
}

let arr = Array.from({length: 1000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000));
let sorted = mergeSort([...arr]);
let sorted2 = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b); // verify
console.log(sorted+"" === sorted2+""); // output verification result
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! :) It took me a moment to wrap my head around the step logic, but it's very elegant. 

I rewrote my algorithm to similarly rely on push, but using reassignment instead of steps. I believe it's equivalent? 

https://gist.github.com/juliettepretot/d8d9455c5556a1f3cc3e1a0ab5575849

Comment: Yes, having a brief look, that looks fine. The difference being that you first store the merged subarrays in a separate array `sortedArr`, and then assign that back to `arr`. So you have the arrays of two subsequent merge phases living together until the end of a merge phase, and then you kick out  `arr` as you make it reference the newer array `sortedArr`. This may be cleaner. I just want to point out that with the `delete` I have in my answer, memory is released earlier to the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it! Yup, fair point. Eventually memory is released in my implementation as well, but not as quickly. I could probably add delete statements to release it earlier as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is `O(n^2)` but with good constants.

The problem is that `arr.splice` is a `O(n)` operation and there is no way to optimize it.  You are taking 2 values out of the middle of the array and then having to move everything else over.  That move operation is highly optimized, but is still `O(n)`.

Instead use `shift`/`push` to get rid of that problem.  This will cause elements to "rotate" through the array.  (Actually the array will travel in memory until it gets moved, then travel in memory again.  But this should all be nicely optimized.)

```
function mergeSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = [arr[i]]
  }
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    let elt1 = arr.shift()
    let elt2 = arr.shift()
    arr.push(mergeTwoSortedArrays(elt1, elt2))
  }
  return arr[0]
}
```

(Side note, I kept your style.  But oh boy did I want to sprinkle `;` around in a few places!)

Comment: According to ECMAScript specs [`shift`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.shift) involves iteration over the keys, where [[Get]] and [[Set]] operations are executed. I suppose in some cases engines may find optimisations... but not sure that *O(1)* may be assumed.

Comment: @trincot Hrm, I thought that they all optimized that one. 
 According to https://lannonbr.com/blog/2020-01-27-shift-optimizations it is fast in Firefox, and fast in Chrome..up to 50k items in the array.  Oh well.  In more sensible languages that version is as fast as I said...